# Custom Post type archives / categories give 404

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, archives

I have a client that wants a blog, a press section, and a "More Posts" section for feel good, community service type of posts. I used the standard post type for the blog, and everything works fine. I registered the two other post types with this code which is within a `custom_posts();` function that I add with `add_action( 'init', 'custom_posts');`

```
register_post_type( 'press',
    // let's now add all the options for this post type
    array( 'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Press', 'bonestheme' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Press', 'bonestheme' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Press', 'bonestheme' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'bonestheme' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Post', 'bonestheme' ), 
        'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'bonestheme' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Post', 'bonestheme' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Post', 'bonestheme' ), 
        'view_item' => __( 'View Post', 'bonestheme' ), 
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Posts', 'bonestheme' ),  
        'not_found' =>  __( 'Nothing found in the Database.', 'bonestheme' ), 
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nothing found in Trash', 'bonestheme' ), 
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
        ), 
        'description' => __( 'Press', 'bonestheme' ), 
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_position' => 8, 
        'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'press-posts' ),
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'revisions', 'sticky', 'custom-fields', 'editor', 'author' )
    )
);

register_post_type( 'more_posts',
    array( 'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'More Posts', 'bonestheme' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Post', 'bonestheme' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Posts', 'bonestheme' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'bonestheme' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Post', 'bonestheme' ), 
        'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'bonestheme' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Post', 'bonestheme' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Post', 'bonestheme' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Post', 'bonestheme' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Posts', 'bonestheme' ),
        'not_found' =>  __( 'Nothing found in the Database.', 'bonestheme' ), 
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nothing found in Trash', 'bonestheme' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
        ),
        'description' => __( 'More Posts', 'bonestheme' ), 
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_position' => 9,  
        'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'more-posts' ),
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'revisions', 'sticky', 'custom-fields', 'editor', 'author' ),
    )
);
```

I am adding the taxonomies with this code, also in the `custom_posts();` function:

```
    register_taxonomy( 'press_cat', 
    array('press'), /* if you change the name of register_post_type( 'press', then you have to change this */
    array('hierarchical' => true,     /* if this is true, it acts like categories */
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Categories', 'bonestheme' ), /* name of the custom taxonomy */
            'singular_name' => __( 'Press Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* single taxonomy name */
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Press Categories', 'bonestheme' ), /* search title for taxomony */
            'all_items' => __( 'All Press Categories', 'bonestheme' ), /* all title for taxonomies */
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Press Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* parent title for taxonomy */
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Press Category:', 'bonestheme' ), /* parent taxonomy title */
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Press Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* edit custom taxonomy title */
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Press Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* update title for taxonomy */
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Press Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* add new title for taxonomy */
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Press Category Name', 'bonestheme' ) /* name title for taxonomy */
        ),
        'show_admin_column' => true, 
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'press-posts-category' )
    )
);
register_taxonomy( 'more_cat', 
    array('more_posts'), /* if you change the name of register_post_type( 'more-posts', then you have to change this */
    array('hierarchical' => true,     /* if this is true, it acts like categories */
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Categories', 'bonestheme' ), /* name of the custom taxonomy */
            'singular_name' => __( 'Post Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* single taxonomy name */
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Posts Categories', 'bonestheme' ), /* search title for taxomony */
            'all_items' => __( 'All Posts Categories', 'bonestheme' ), /* all title for taxonomies */
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Posts Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* parent title for taxonomy */
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Posts Category:', 'bonestheme' ), /* parent taxonomy title */
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Posts Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* edit custom taxonomy title */
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Posts Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* update title for taxonomy */
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Posts Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* add new title for taxonomy */
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Posts Category Name', 'bonestheme' ) /* name title for taxonomy */
        ),
        'show_admin_column' => true, 
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'more-posts-category' )
    )
);
```

**Press** - archive is broken(404) when using custom permalinks (works fine with std perma)

**More** - archive is broken(404) when using custom permalinks (works fine with std perma)

**More** - category gives me a page, but returns no posts (there are 2 posts in there)

I am using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-widgets/) plugin to create the archive and category lists on the sidebar, it seems to be functioning correctly. The URLs it gives me are:

/press/2015/02/  -  press archives

/more_posts/2015/02/  -  more archive

/more-posts-category/giving-back/  -  more categories

Comment: what action do you call this code on? and what urls are you visiting to see your archives?

Comment: Updated above with answers

Answer (score 0):

Custom post type archives don't have year/month rewrite rules, they only have a single archive which will be at `/press/` and `/more_posts/`. If you want those, you'll have to [add them yourself](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). For the taxonomy, add the `taxonomies` argument to your post type registration to insure the two objects are connected, see the note about this on [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Taxonomies).

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to tell what code is relevant to put up for the purpose of the question. I was actually already adding the taxonomies. I updated my question above.